# How to style lightDOM from shadowDOM (without using ::content)?

Tags: html, polymer, dart-polymer, shadow-dom

I try so solve the following problem. Please, see example:

**custom-elements.html**

```
<polymer-element name="ui-nav" class="_row _columned _cols-2 mobile_cols-12" noscript>
  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**index.html**

```
<ui-nav>
  <div>Привет русским</div>
  <div>Контакты</div>
  <div>О себе</div>
</ui-nav>
```

**main.css**

```
._row {display: block;}
._row [class*="_cols-"] {float:left;}
._cols-2 > * {width: 20%;}
...
```

The example above works as expected: all the styles applied to `ui-nav` (using classes) inherited by all `div` child elements. However, what if I need to add additional classes to `ui-nav` in different case? For example

```
<ui-nav> <!-- case 1 -->
  <div>Content</div>
  ...
</ui-nav>

<ui-nav class="border-green"> <!-- case 2 -->
  <div>Another content</div>
  ...
</ui-nav>
```

In the example `border-green` will break the logic, because it overwrites predefined classes previously defined in class attribute of `polymer-element`. I tried to apply classes on `content` tag, but it doesn't work. As well as the following form doesn't work too:

```
<polymer-element name="ui-nav" noscript>
  <template>
    <div class="_row _columned _cols-2 mobile_cols-12">
      <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

So how can I apply already existing classes like `_row _cols-2` to the elements of lightDOM without defining additional classes/styles using `::shadow`, `::content` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.

You could include your stylesheet that contains these styles in your template, and use the last option where you wrap the content in a div with those classes, but that is likely to have some performance issues as the stylesheets will be inlined at runtime.

The only other option really is to use some shadow boundary piercing selector like ::shadow, /deep/, etc from your main stylesheet.